# Delete first item in array and keep keys index

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to delete the first key and value from an array while keeping the keys.

I can't seem to get this working with all the array possibilities.

Here's my $mag_cats_arr:

```
Array ( [6] => Science [9] => hashgraph [4] => Blockchain )
```

With array_slice, the keys are reset, but I need them:

```
$mag_cats_arr = array_slice($mag_cats_arr,1);
Array ( [0] => hashgraph [0] => Blockchain ) (Science is gone here)
```

How do I keep the keys when removing the first ([6] => Science) in this array?

Comment: Do you just want to remove it or do you actually want the value too?  If the former, see [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With array_slice, the keys are reset

`array_slice()` has a fourth parameter that prevents re-indexing the result array. Cf. http://php.net/array-slice

Comment: Thanks! I should read better, but now I have this: $mag_cats_arr = array_slice($mag_cats_arr,1,99,TRUE); - Is there like an infinite value for 99? For when you don't know how big the array is?

Comment: I fixed that comment above with: count($mag_cats_arr);

Comment: use `NULL` (as shown in the function description) or `count($mag_cats_arr)`.

Answer (score 1):

simple, assuming you want to remove the first element of the array and have not done a foreach or other process on it.

```
 unset($mag_cats_arr[key($mag_cats_array)]);
```

The `key()` function returns the first element (or wherever the pointer is) and `unset` removes it.

Note : if you have done some operations on the array (such as a loop) then don't forget to `reset` the array

Comment: `Note : if you have done some operations then don't forget to reset the array` say what?

Comment: if you run the array through any loop or you move the index pointer you need to do `reset($mag_cats_array);` to set it back to beginning

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  `reset, unset, and key` are all PHP4 - 7 functions.  `array_slice` didn't support `preserve keys` in PHP4 - Oh , he deleted his comment